# Magento "confirm link" expiration period

Tags: magento, email

Is there a way (an extension, maybe?) to set an expiration period for the link sent with the account confirmation email?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about older versions, but Magento 1.7 or 1.8 comes with the functionality to set the expiry period for the confirmation link.

Goto System > Configuration > Customer Configuration:

**Under create new account options** enter the value for **Email Confirmation Link Expiration Period (days)**

Comment: I do not find any such functionality in Magento1.9.2.2